# VB.NET/CR - Show Specific Row Data in Crystal Report

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

i need to show specific row data into report, here my query dataset

```
Private Function loadDS(noTransaksi)

ds = Nothing
        ds = New DataSet()
        Dim query As String

        query = "SELECT
  tbl_transaksi.no_transaksi,
  tbl_transaksi.tgl_transaksi,
  tbl_toko.nama_toko,
  tbl_barang.nama_barang,
  tbl_transaksi_detail.qty,
  tbl_transaksi_detail.unit,
  tbl_transaksi_detail.harga_satuan,
  tbl_transaksi_detail.total_harga

FROM

    tbl_toko
  INNER JOIN
    tbl_transaksi
  ON
    tbl_toko.tbl_toko_id = tbl_transaksi.id_toko

INNER JOIN
  (
    tbl_barang
  INNER JOIN
    tbl_transaksi_detail
  ON
    tbl_barang.tbl_barang_id = tbl_transaksi_detail.id_barang
  )
ON
  tbl_transaksi.no_transaksi = tbl_transaksi_detail.no_transaksi where tbl_transaksi.no_transaksi = " & Integer.Parse(noTransaksi)
        Try
            strcon.Open()

            da = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, strcon)

            da.Fill(ds)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        strcon.Close()
Return ds
    End Function
```

I have try this query directly in phpmyadmin, and it works fine, but why I can't display only 'this' specific data row in my report?

here my code to load crystal report previewer

```
noTrans = formTransaksiToko.noTrans
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds = loadDS(noTrans)
        Dim report As New ReportDocument
        report.Load("fakturJadi.rpt")
        report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

result in phpmyadmin
[image]

note : field `tbl_transaksi.no_transaksi` is integer datatype

Comment: The query you showed us a) does not return a single record, at least not explicitly, and b) has other issues.  For instance, the subquery does not have an alias.  Are you sure this query works elsewhere?

Comment: yes, my query is working in phpmyadmin, I tried change the `tbl_transaksi.no_transaksi = " & Integer.Parse(noTransaksi)` to `tbl_transaksi.no_transaksi = 1` in phpmyadmin, it return 2 result